# How can write a program in scheme to find factors of a list of numbers

Tags: list, dictionary, scheme, factors, cdr

This is the code for a single integer, how can it extends to list of function?

```
(define (factors n)
      (define (*factors d)
        (cond ((> d n) (list))
              ((= (modulo n d) 0) (cons d (*factors (+ d 1))))
              (else (*factors (+ d 1)))))
      (*factors 1))
    
    (display (factors 1111111))
    (newline)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for-each` to iterate over a list.

```
(define (factors n)
  (define (*factors d)
    (cond ((> d n) (list))
          ((= (modulo n d) 0) (cons d (*factors (+ d 1))))
          (else (*factors (+ d 1)))))
  (*factors 1))

(define arbitarily-large-input (list 10 11 12))

(for-each (lambda (x)
            (display x)
            (newline))
          (map factors arbitarily-large-input))
```

Comment: How can i write the same program by defining a list

Comment: How can i extend the program to take arbitarily large input

Comment: @safump I have no idea what you are asking.